# lock drawing pad (mouse pen pad) to <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a [mousepen pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgOYq.jpg). I wrote a drawing app with Javascript for it and I can use it with full functionality. When I connect the pad to pc, it acts like a mouse. It fits the whole screen, but my drawing canvas is not that big.

I want the pad to fit (map) into the canvas. So, when I point in the top-right corner of the pad with the pen pointer, it currently points in the top-right corner of the PC's screen, but I want it to only point in teh top-right corner of my div.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm afraid you can not override your OS functionality with _JavaScript_. why don't you make your _drawing app_ full-screen?

Comment: EhsanT: I don't know to what extent this qualifies as OS functionality, though it would certainly need web API work, and would presumably involve the browser asking the user for permission.  But it doesn't seem to be a question about "[how] can I configure my device/OS to do this" but "[how] can my app ask for this".

Comment: @SamB, _I want the pad to fit (map) into the canvas. So, when I point in the top-right corner of the pad with the pen pointer, it currently points in the top-right corner of the PC's screen, but I want it to only point in the top-right corner of my div._. So I'm not 100% sure, but I do not think you can limit the position of the mouse pointer with _JavaScript_, that what OS controls. Then what if the user scrolls out of that area? can we control that the pointer do not go outside that area?!